# SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database: create locale table failed

Tags: android, sqlite

Всем привет, вот такой вопрос меня мучает уже несколько дней:

> CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
>
> Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
>
> net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database: create locale table failed

Вот код работы с Sqlcipher:

```
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements DataStore {
        private static DBHelper sInstance;
        private String DBKey;

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DBConst.DB_NAME, null, DBConst.DB_VERSION);
        }

        public static synchronized DBHelper getInstance() {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(App.getContext());
                sInstance = new DBHelper(App.getContext());
            }
            return sInstance;
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(createTable(DBConst.TABLE_NAME));
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(dropTable(DBConst.TABLE_NAME));
            onCreate(db);
        }

        private String createTable(String name) {
            return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  " + name + " (" +
                    DBConst.DB_ID + " integer primary key," +
                    DBConst.DB_DATA + " text);";
        }

        private String dropTable(String name) {
            return "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + name;
        }

        public synchronized void deleteTable(String name) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(getDBKey());
            db.delete(name, null, null);
            db.close();
        }

        private String getDBKey() {
            if (DBKey == null)
                DBKey = PreferencesStorage.getInstance().getDBKey();
            return DBKey;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void writeData(NoSqlEntity entity, String tableName) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(getDBKey());
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(DBConst.DB_ID, entity.entityId);
            cv.put(DBConst.DB_DATA, entity.entityData);
            db.insert(tableName, null, cv);
            db.close();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized <T> List<T> readAllData(Class<T> clazz, String tableName) {
            ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(getDBKey());
            Cursor c = db.query(tableName,
                    new String[]{
                            DBConst.DB_ID, DBConst.DB_DATA
                    }, null, null, null, null, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    list.add(new GsonSerialization().deserializeFromDB(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBConst.DB_DATA)), clazz));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
            db.close();
            return list;
        }
}
```

Если ключ к бд захардкодить константой, то проблем нет.

Из PreferencesStorage ключ правильный.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я предполагаю что ошибка появляется в версии Android M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в режиме отладки длина у ключа и возращаемого значения из PreferenceStorage совпадает?

Есть вот такое issue при работе с SharedPreferences - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159799